# Codeigniter Tank auth installation

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I'm having some problems with Tank Auth.
Although i followed the instructions [from here](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) when i try to connect in the login_form i get a redirect in http://example.com/auth/login.

I assume i can change "example.com" with my domain but i can't find where.
The other thing is that captcha is not showing.

I suppose i have to learn only from the examples coming with the installation?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there is no 'example.com' in the latest version of Tank Auth. Have you changed the base url in the CI config file? Its at ./system/application/config/config.php the line

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/";
```

Whats wrong with capcha? Have you set up all of the directories for your images?

Comment: I changed the base url and it is working.Thank you.What do you mean set up the directories for images?

Comment: @Stavros If you're using the .htaccess file to remove the "index.php" from your CodeIgniter URLs, you should make sure it's not rewriting requests for Tank Auth's "captcha" directory. For example, the RewriteCond line in my .htaccess file looks like `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css|captcha)` -- the last entry in that list ensures that Tank Auth's CAPTCHA images get displayed correctly from the "captcha" directory you copied into your CI install when adding Tank Auth.

Comment: If you are using the CI captcha plugin, then you must set up the directories for the images as stated in the CI plugin file, in the lines 'img_path' => './captcha/', 'img_url' => 'http://example.com/captcha/'.

Comment: It's likely your permissions aren't right in the captcha directory. Give it a `chmod -R 777 captcha` to see if that's the problem. You might massage the chmod value to make it more restrictive

Answer (score 2):

Here are some (more detailed) instructions on getting Tank Auth to work in CodeIgniter:
http://expertnotfound.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/setting-up-tank-auth-2/

(Sadly it does not seem to be 100% compatible with CI 2.1.0. But it still made a difference for me...)